# how to Send Email details notification using php?

Tags: php, email

How can I send email notification to my users who gave registration details in my form using php?

I have code which runs perfectly to get emails to me, but now I also want to same details to my users.

I am trying to use "$from" into my array at "$to" but getting no email.

my **mail.php**

```
<?php

$subject = "Email Notification";
$message = "Thank you for your email";
$message = "Your Registering details are as follows:";
$message .= "<br><br>";
$message .= "<table border='1'>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Name</td><td>".$_POST['name']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Email</td><td>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";

$from = $_POST['email'];
$to =  array('my_address@example.com', 'my_address2@example.com', $from);
$lp = "notification@example.com";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 

$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 

$headers .=  'from: '.$lp .'' . "\r\n" .

            'Reply-To: '.$lp.'' . "\r\n" .

            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

foreach($to as $row)
{
   mail($row,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

echo "Mail Sent.";
die;
?>
```

Comment: So you're saying this code works but not everyone receives the emails?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just ending up in there Spam/Junk folder?

Comment: For one thing, you're missing a dot for `$message = "Your Registering details are as follows:";` - that alone will break it. Plus, make sure your form's elements are indeed `name`'d.

Comment: Plus, you need to place this `$from = $_POST['email'];` **before** `$subject = "Email Notification";`. In not doing so, you are not defining it. It's kind of like putting the wagon before the horse.

Comment: I tested your code and with no problems. Make sure they haven't ended up in Spam or probably rejected by your server and/or blacklisted from certain Email services like Gmail, Yahoo, etc.

Comment: I hate when someone posts a question and then walks away.

Comment: @fred-ii :-I mean, email are receiving to my end perfectly, but also want send same email notification to my user on who have entered their email addaress....

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty common that on shared hosting you need to send an email from an "existing email", at least match the domain. Maybe that's why the emails are not being sent?

So for example, if your domain is "www.my-awesome-domain.com", you can't send email headers

```
"from: example@example.com"
```

Instead, make sure to send emails from your domain, and ideally an existing email box, for example:

```
"from: office@my-awesome-domain.com"
```

Hope it helps! :)